# CentOS: installing a PHP module without updating PHP

Tags: php, centos

I am running PHP 5.3.5.

Now I need to install the `php-mbstring` module.

When I run:

```
yum install php-mbstring
```

I am asked to update PHP:

```
Installing:
 php-mbstring                              x86_64                              5.3.6-3.el5.remi                                remi                              2.3 M
Updating for dependencies:
 mysql                                     x86_64                              5.5.11-1.el5.remi                               remi                              7.4 M
 mysql-libs                                x86_64                              5.5.11-1.el5.remi                               remi                              1.1 M
 mysql-server                              x86_64                              5.5.11-1.el5.remi                               remi                               12 M
 php                                       x86_64                              5.3.6-3.el5.remi                                remi                              1.4 M
 php-cli                                   x86_64                              5.3.6-3.el5.remi                                remi                              2.6 M
 php-common                                x86_64                              5.3.6-3.el5.remi                                remi                              973 k
 php-devel                                 x86_64                              5.3.6-3.el5.remi                                remi                              623 k
 php-gd                                    x86_64                              5.3.6-3.el5.remi                                remi                              208 k
 php-mysql                                 x86_64                              5.3.6-3.el5.remi                                remi                              159 k
 php-pdo                                   x86_64                              5.3.6-3.el5.remi                                remi                              117 k
 php-xml                                   x86_64                              5.3.6-3.el5.remi                                remi                              221 k

Transaction Summary
=======================================================================================================================================================================
Install      1 Package(s)         
Update      11 Package(s)         
Remove       0 Package(s)
```

How can I install the module for the PHP version 5.3.5 so that I can avoid updating PHP?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a specific version of a package with YUM, you append a dash and the version to the package name.  But the versions used by YUM/RPM are slightly different from the official versions, as shown by the version column in the output you provided.  So first, run `yum info` to check what version you have installed:

```
yum info installed php
```

Once you've figured that out, then you can install the right version.  For example, if the installed version was `5.3.6-1.el5.remi`, you'd run:

```
yum install php-mbstring-5.3.5-1.el5.remi
```

That being said, PHP 5.3.6 [fixes 6 security bugs and over 60 other problems](http://php.net/releases/5_3_6.php).  It introduces no major changes and will not break existing applications.  You really should upgrade.

Comment: No package php-mbstring-5.3.5-1.el5.remi available.

Comment: @andufo:  It looks like Remi keeps only one old version of a package around at one time.

Comment: @Patches yes, i changed your line for php-mbstring-5.3.8-1.el5.remi.1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the system package manager to install a php module. It is useful for the Php website develoment. Hope this helps.